# Trim string to the end of the second instance of a specified argument

Tags: php, substr

I'm trying to trim up a string to the end of the `second` paragraph, so essentially the end of the second instance of `</p>`

I have some code already to trim it to 500 characters, to the nearest space. How could I do something like this but with a `</p>` as the parameter instead, and a variable length (the paragraphs can be long).

I also need to add a check to see if the entire post content is sub 300 chars, in which case I can output the whole thing

This is the code I have which is similar, but not sure how to adapt it. How would you do this?

```
if (strlen($content) > 300){
    $content_trimmed = substr($content, 0, strpos($content, ' ', 500));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This function will return the first two paragraphs:

```
<?php

$content = "<p>Paragraph One</p><p>Paragraph Two</p><p>Paragraph Three</p>";

function trimArticle($content) {
    if (strlen($content) > 300) {
        $paragraphs = explode('</p>', $content);
        return $paragraphs[0].'</p>'.$paragraphs[1].'</p>';
    } else {
        return $content;
    }
}

echo trimArticle($content);

?>
```

Has this result:

```
<p>Paragraph One</p><p>Paragraph Two</p>
```

Comment: Works well, thanks. Now I just need to work out how to assign a class to the <p> it outputs. Thanks!

Comment: That could be handled by replacing <p> with <p class='myClass'>

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to check the length and then use explode to grab that parts. Then add the missing closing paragraph tag that explode grabbed and concatenate the first two array elements.

```
if (strlen($content) > 300){
$content = explode("</p>",$content) ;
$content_trimmed = $content[0]."</p>".$content[1]."</p>";
} else {
            $content_trimmed = $content;
       }
echo $content_trimmed;
```

Comment: See [my comment](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/26554126/2) about my edit. Your answer does contain a syntax error in `$content_trimmed = $content[0]."</p>.$content[1]."</p>";` missing quote. That's why indenting is important, instead of using ticks. It's better to "indent".